# How can I find a user's GEO Location using ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, firefox, google-chrome, asp.net-2.0, geolocation

How can I get hold of a user's GEO location within my ASP.NET application? I've noticed on browsers like Firefox and Google Chrome, I (as the user) am prompted as to whether or not to allow the site to have access to my location.

How can I achieve a similar thing to this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The prompt you're seeing is shown when a site uses the [Geolocation API](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html). It's all JavaScript, so you don't need any kind of server support to use it. If you want the values on the server side, you can send them back using XMLHttpRequest or a simple form post.

[Here's a demo](http://html5demos.com/geo) with easy to read source code as well.

Comment: Cheers Matti, I didn't realise it was so simple!

Answer (score 5):

Use the regular [HTML5 Geolocation](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html) tools to get the location and then use AJAX to send the location back to your ASP.NET Server Side code and update whatever client elements are necessary.

Comment: What happens if the user disables JavaScript? Having the ability to do geolocation server side would be good for preventing this. Any pointers you could give?

Comment: @RickSibley In these days people who disable JavaScript are considered to be from the stone age, so this is a very rare condition, Also, location service depends on many factors like GPS on mobile phones, and Public IP addresses in desktop PCs, so the server side may have no clue how to get these parameters, although it can get the IP!