# Get timezone by current culture info with c#

Tags: c#, c#-5.0

I need to know the timezone for a certain language which I get from the current culture info object.

I can not use 3rd party libs like nodatime.

What property of the CultureInfo.CurrentCulture is important when I enumerate through all system time zones and want to get the right timezone?

Comment: I don't think cultures and timezones are necessarily correlated...

Comment: There is no one to one mapping between culture and time zones, for example for `en-US` you could end up with many timezones (Eastern,pacific, central etc).

Comment: Best you can do - get a timezone interval [for eg. Russia - UTC+2...UTC+12]

Comment: Have you looked at TimeZoneInfo.Local? "Gets a TimeZoneInfo object that represents the local time zone." https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.local(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I can not get the timezone of the computer running the code if its a web server... I need to get a correlation between timezone and the language setting of the user.

Comment: Coincidentally I saw this article today: http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2015/Feb/10/Back-to-Basics-UTC-and-TimeZones-in-NET-Web-Apps It may be of some help.

Comment: My Problem with all the timezone samples is this: TimeZoneId = "Hawaiian Standard Time" FROM WHERE comes this id? sorry for screaming...

Comment: I suspect that you are looking for [How do I enumerate all time zones in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/442019/how-do-i-enumerate-all-time-zones-in-net), but it have absolutely nothing in common with current question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all you've got is culture, that's basically some string like: `MX (Spanish Mexico), es-CO (Spanish Columbia), and fr-CA (French Canada)` then you just have to correspond each on of these to a timezone, except no such one to one relationship exists. So no. You can roughly know the timezone (as pointed out in comments), fr-CA is all in the same timezone, but MX is in four (MX isn't enough information to gauge timezone).

So you don't have enough data to know, what can you do. If you need to know their timezone on the server side try geo-location:
[How can I find a user's GEO Location using ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753022/how-can-i-find-a-users-geo-location-using-asp-net)

However, if it's just the web page that needs to know, try putting that logic in the JavaScript which is executing on their machine.

Or you could just... ask them.

Comment: but if there exist no such 1 to 1 relationship, how can I find the current timezone ?

Comment: yes... but from which variable do you get the "Tokyo Standardd Time" ?

Comment: Give an example of your data.

Comment: of which data? I mean I have only the culture of the logged in user. which is an culture info object.

Comment: Note that you can approximately map timezone to country where given language/country is used, but it have almost nothing to do with what timezone current user uses - such user can use computer in different country altogether but still keep preferred culture.

Comment: @NathanCooper having more info now... but what if I have ru-RU and I want to get all time zones for ru-RU? How would you do that? I saw today in the code, that the user might have to select a 'State/Region' from a dropdown additionally to the selected country. So I have 2 information pieces now Country and the state.