# passing location into code behind after button click event C# ASP.Net HTML5

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, html

So I have tried so many resources on the internet to get the current users latitude and longitude to be passed into the code behind of my C# asp.net website and still have not found a working solution.

So basically when a user clicks the search button on my website, I have to get his current GEO location and pass that through to the code behind. Please keep in mind that this means I already have a click event called "Submit_Search".

For there I plan on calculating distance, but if I can just get these 2 variables in code behind on the button event, I'd be ever grateful!.

I have tried adding the javascript in the header of the site master.
I have tried just adding the javascript in the design view with a hidden asp field. 
I have tried switching it around and moving the JS to an external file and referencing it.
But none of these seem to work in visual studio 2014 and HTML5 (using web forms with site master application).

Please, can someone assist?

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Show some of your efforts

Comment: some code would be useful, but are the coordinates being calculated correctly? If so Id suggest adding using some javascript to set values in the form or intercept submit click and add values then.

Comment: [This other question could help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3753054/5363465) and here is the [code](https://html5demos.com/geo/#view-source)

Comment: The example provided is one of the things I've tried, my only problem here is that I need to be able to use the Lat and Long in the code behind. So I have managed to get the location fine, but not how to pass it to the code behind. Have tried hidden asp field with Runat="server", but then the javascript does not assign any value to the field on button click.